# How to add a text on the top of GLSurfaceview with transparent background in android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

Hi im having a parent viewgroup which has a background, contains a openglview as a part of that viewgroup.

What I want exactly is, i need a openglview with a transparent background and I want to able to see the parent background and I want to be able to write text on top of openglview,  **I dont want to use textures**.

I tried this options,

1. Setting the openglview **zorderontop as true**. It makes my text to go behind the glview. If im not making zorderontop true, the background is black.
2. Setting the **transluent theme** to the activity which makes my glview and also the **parent view group to become transparent**.
3. I tried to inflate the layout contains the glview and use **ContexThemeWrapper** class to change the theme of the glview dynamically. But **setTheme() not working** at runtime. only applying theme in manifest file it works.
4. Applying the layout backgroud to transparent also didnt work, still black background.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're drawing to two separate surfaces: one surface created by ViewRoot, and one surface created for the GLSurfaceView. These surfaces are composited by SurfaceFlinger, one on top of the other. (By default the ViewRoot surface will be on top and the GLSurfaceView surface will be on bottom.)

Since all of your Views are drawn into the ViewRoot's surface, they must all be on top of the OpenGL surface or beneath the OpenGL surface.

If you don't want to use textures, period, your only choice is to create a third surface, this time with SurfaceView instead of GLSurfaceView, to draw your text above the GLSurfaceView.

Comment: hi matthew, thanks a lot for your reply. I will try this approach now and Let you know. thank you again.

Comment: Hi, I am facing one more problem now. I having the glsurfaceview which I set the zorderontop(true) (becoz i need my surfaceview on top of the normal view). im having the surfaceview on a scrollview and in the screen im having a dashboard layout on top of the screen. 
when I scroll the glsurfaceview is moving on top of glsurfaceview. can you please help me out?

Comment: You probably don't want to put a SurfaceView inside a ScrollView. Handle the scrolling yourself by calling canvas.translate before drawing.

Comment: but in the scroll im not having only my glview, i have listview also. the other views which is in scroll is going below the dashboard but the glsurfaceview creating the problem by moving top of the dashboard layout.